# Mass Remove Prefix From A File. Png File

Tags: cmd.exe

So here is a folder:
[image]

These files have a prefix number in the start its hard to rename every file is there a way i can do with command prompt? or anything else?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with a Batch file (*.bat*) script.

Create a new text file and paste the following code into it:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

for %%F in (????_*.png) do (
    set "filename=%%~nxF"
    ren "%%F" "!filename:~5!"
)
```

Save the file with a *.bat* extension, for example *remove_prefix.bat*, in the same folder where your PNG files are located.

Double-click the batch file to run it. It will iterate through all PNG files in the folder that have filenames starting with four digits and an underscore, and it will remove the prefix, leaving only the rest of the filename.

---

You can also the the same thing in Command Prompt directly (no need to save a *.bat* file and then run) using the follwoing command:

`for %F in (????_*.png) do @for /f "tokens=1* delims=_" %A in ("%F") do @ren "%F" "%B"`

Comment: Sorry, I missed that.